# Flex items don't stretch container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

There is parent container with children flexbox container.

Flexbox container has two chidren. The width of flexbox container should be defined by two child blocks.

In fact, the parent element does not stretch across the width of the two children. It takes a width that is not specified anywhere.

I determined that the problem is in the property: `position:relative` of the parent block where the flexbox container placed.

Why does this property affect the width of the flexbox container? How can I fix this error?

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzEJwE) on Codepen.

```css
.openned-0-40 .box-0-33 {
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  height: 405pxpx;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.box-0-33 {
  width: auto;
  height: 405px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  padding-right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-0-45 {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 {
  flex-basis: 185px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 55px;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 .header-0-36 {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.header-0-36 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Semibold, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 .item-0-49 {
  font-family: Proxima Nova Light, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.item-0-49 {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 6px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Light, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin-left: -6px;
  user-select: none;
  margin-bottom: 4.9px;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 .item-0-49 span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.flag-icon-cn {
  background-image: url(/static/media/cn.5d831425.svg);
}

.flag-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.33333333em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.allCountriesWrapper-0-44 {
  text-align: center;
}

.header-0-36 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Semibold, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.allCountries-0-46 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

.column-0-47 {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.itemWrapper-0-48 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.inputBox-0-31 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputBox-0-31 openned-0-40">
  <div class="box-0-33">
    <div class="content-0-45">
      <div class="popularCountries-0-42">
        <div class="header-0-36">Популярные направления:</div>
        <div class="popularCountriesList-0-43">
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cn"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 286 -->Китай
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-at"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 289 -->Австрия
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aw"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 292 -->Аруба
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bh"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 295 -->Бахрейн
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-be"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 298 -->Бельгия
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bg"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 301 -->Болгария
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hu"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 304 -->Венгрия
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49">
            <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hk"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 307 -->Гонконг
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="allCountriesWrapper-0-44">
        <div class="header-0-36">Все страны:</div>
        <div class="allCountries-0-46">
          <div class="column-0-47">
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Австрия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Албания</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Аруба</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Бахрейн</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Бельгия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Болгария</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Венгрия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Гонконг</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Греция</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Дания</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column-0-47">
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Доминиканская Республика</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Египет</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Индонезия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Иордания</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Ирландия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Испания</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Италия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Камбоджа</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Канада</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Кения</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="column-0-47">
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 activeItem-0-50 item-0-49">Китай</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Куба</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Латвия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Литва</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Маврикий</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Малайзия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Мальдивы</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Норвегия</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Перу</span>
            </div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48">
              <span class="item-0-49 ">Сейшельские острова</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button-0-51" title="Показать все">Показать все</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using *absolute positioning* here and that's why the auto widths are not respected.

Remove `position: absolute` from `box-0-33` (use `relative` instead) and `width: 200px` from `.inputBox-0-31` - see demo below:

```css
.openned-0-40 .box-0-33 {
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  height: 405pxpx;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box-0-33 {
  width: auto;
  height: 405px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 2px 2px;
  padding-right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-0-45 {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 {
  flex-basis: 185px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 55px;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 .header-0-36 {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.header-0-36 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Semibold, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 .item-0-49 {
  font-family: Proxima Nova Light, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.item-0-49 {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 6px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .1s ease;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Light, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin-left: -6px;
  user-select: none;
  margin-bottom: 4.9px;
}

.popularCountries-0-42 .item-0-49 span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 14px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.flag-icon-cn {
  background-image: url(/static/media/cn.5d831425.svg);
}

.flag-icon {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.33333333em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.allCountriesWrapper-0-44 {
  text-align: center;
}

.header-0-36 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Proxima Nova Semibold, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.allCountries-0-46 {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

.column-0-47 {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.itemWrapper-0-48 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.inputBox-0-31 {
  /*width: 200px;*/
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputBox-0-31 openned-0-40">
  <div class="box-0-33">
    <div class="content-0-45">
      <div class="popularCountries-0-42">
        <div class="header-0-36">Популярные направления:</div>
        <div class="popularCountriesList-0-43">
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cn"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 286 -->Китай
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-at"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 289 -->Австрия
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aw"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 292 -->Аруба
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bh"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 295 -->Бахрейн
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-be"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 298 -->Бельгия
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bg"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 301 -->Болгария
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hu"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 304 -->Венгрия
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
          <div class="item-0-49"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hk"></span>
            <!-- react-text: 307 -->Гонконг
            <!-- /react-text -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="allCountriesWrapper-0-44">
        <div class="header-0-36">Все страны:</div>
        <div class="allCountries-0-46">
          <div class="column-0-47">
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Австрия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Албания</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Аруба</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Бахрейн</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Бельгия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Болгария</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Венгрия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Гонконг</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Греция</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Дания</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="column-0-47">
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Доминиканская Республика</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Египет</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Индонезия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Иордания</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Ирландия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Испания</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Италия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Камбоджа</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Канада</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Кения</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="column-0-47">
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 activeItem-0-50 item-0-49">Китай</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Куба</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Латвия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Литва</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Маврикий</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Малайзия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Мальдивы</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Норвегия</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Перу</span></div>
            <div class="itemWrapper-0-48"><span class="item-0-49 ">Сейшельские острова</span></div>
          </div>
        </div><button class="button-0-51" title="Показать все">Показать все</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RichardDavis let me know if this worked for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using .inputBox-0-31 with fixed width on the main parent which holds your flex child. Remove that css class.